# Can't use GBP (£) symbol in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have English version of Excel and Polish regional settings. I try to make a code which will give cells formatting with pound symbol before number value.

Unfortunately it is converted to "L" when I paste the symbol to VBA window. Macro recorder also records cells formatted this way as "L". Chr(163) returns "Ł".

Changing system language setting, localization settings or keyboard settings had no effect. Only after changing regional settings (requires PC restart) to English (Great Britain) it works correctly. Is there any way I could use this symbol without changing regional settings?

Comment: What are the current regional settings? have you run a loop through `Chr(i)` with i being an incremental integer to see is it's a different `Chr` (though I doubt this)?

Comment: Can you escape it as \£

Comment: Have you tried `ChrW(163)`?

Comment: Why do you need to see it like  `£` in the VB Editor? I mean, if you have `L` for it, when you paste back the `L` to Excel it should be `£`. At least it is like this with the German `öäüß`.

Comment: `ChrW(163)` works! I have tried looping all Chr(i) and there was no £. Also escaping does not work. Pasting back to Excel resulted in character being displayed the same was as in VB Editor, meaning L or Ł.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to apply the symbol to the formatting via *VBA*, try:

```
Sub Serling()
    Const g = "General"
    dq = Chr(34)
    sterl = " " & ChrW(163)
    s = g & dq & sterl & dq
    Selection.NumberFormat = s
    Selection.Font.Name = "Arial Unicode MS"
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To me, this is really cool.  If you want degrees Celsius, use ChrW(8451): if you want degrees Fahrenheit, use ChrW(8457), etc.

Comment: Just a minor point, `sterl` should be at the front of the number as per OP request, but that can be easily done looking at your fine solution.